# Problem in parallelizing a function (LSTM model)

Tags: python, list, function, parallel-processing

I have a function, named `fit_model` that takes one input, `dataset`, and does some preprocessing operations on the dataset and runs an LSTM model on it and finally returns a number. So briefly is like below:

```
def fit_model(dataset):
    do some preprocess on the dataset
    train the model on the dataset

    return a number
```

And also I have a list, named `my_list` that contains 21 datasets (Each dataset is in the form of a pandas dataframe).
When I want to parallelize the function like below:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

results = []

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
results = pool.starmap(fit_model, [(my_list[i]) for i in range(0, 21)])
pool.close()
```

I get this error:

```
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 47, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
TypeError: fit_model() takes 1 positional argument but 44 were given
"""
```

But I don't know what's the problem?
Also when I run the function like this:
`x = fit_model(my_list[4])`, or any other index in the range of (0, 21), I don't get any errors.

Can you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is with how you implement the starmap call. This command suggests you are trying to make a list of seperate tuples which would function as their own iterables:

```
[(my_list[i]) for i in range(0, 21)] # recreates your list [val 1, val 2, val 3, ...]
```

This however produces your initial list again. You could fix it using a trailing comma which does create what I think you are trying to create like:

```
[(my_list[i], ) for i in range(0, 21)] # creates [(val 0), (val 1), (val 2) ...]
```

However this is just creating extra code for you while it is not needed at all I think. What I suggest is that you use map instead of starmap like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
# no need to define results 
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
results = pool.map(fit_model, my_list)
pool.close()
```

Or in my opinion a more pythonic manner:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
    results = pool.map(fit_model, my_list)
```